# my database keeps getting deleted when i reinstall the postgresql helm chart

Tags: bash, charts, kubernetes-helm, bogus

every time when i want to reinstall my PostgreSQL chart on my Kubernetes cluster my database keeps getting deleted, i tried several different charts but the outcome is always the data keeps getting removed

i am using chart from various sources

these are the commands i execute

```
helm uninstall postgresql
kubectl delete pvc data-postgresql-0
helm install postgresql
```

Used host OS: Windows
Used Kubernetes Version: 1.20 on Minikube
Used Helm Version: 3

output of my helm list

```
postgresql      boterham    1               2021-08-11 06:26:26.585734591 +0000 UTC         deployed        postgresql-6.3.12       11.5.0
```

also i am pretty sure that these commands are not meant to be used in a productive environment

Answer (score 0):

The data is persistent in the PV (`PersistentVolume`), i.e the data is stored in in the PV. If you delete the PVC, you also delete the PV, where all the data is stored.